# pre-populate recipients for facebook send form

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using javascript SDK i first have the user authenticate the app
and then get the friend list and pre-populate the to field.

here is what I have so far. gives a vague error

http://www.fbrell.com/saved/fcd3326a3fb5ca0c28e19053df70ab01

Answer (score 0):

If your code was indented properly you would have found your syntax error very fast.

your `function loop(list){` is not closed properly.

`if(list.length != 0){` is closed with `};` delete the `;` and add `}` after it

http://www.fbrell.com/saved/da459800ab32f9ede5d4783bcbe0609d

Enjoy :-)